# C++ overwriting data from parent structure is not working

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

Normally it has no sense and is very unsafe, but only theoretically if there is a way,

Here is example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {
    uint32_t &get() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(this);
    }

    void set(const uint32_t val) {
        *this = *reinterpret_cast<const A *>(&val);
    }
};

struct B : A {
    uint16_t a;
    uint16_t b;

    void set_b(const uint32_t val) {
        *this = *reinterpret_cast<const B *>(&val);
    }
};

main() {
    B k;
    k.a = 0x1234;
    k.b = 0x5678;
    std::cout << std::hex << k.get() << " : " << k.a << " " << k.b << std::endl;
    k.set_b(0x87654321);
    std::cout << std::hex << k.get() << " : " << k.a << " " << k.b << std::endl;
    k.set(0xaabbccdd);
    std::cout << std::hex << k.get() << " : " << k.a << " " << k.b << std::endl;
}
```

I get this result:

```
56781234 : 1234 5678
87654321 : 4321 8765
87654321 : 4321 8765
```

But I except that last should be:

```
aabbccdd : ccdd aabb
```

So, why overwriting data in structure from parent not working?

**Experiment:**

I make one experiment, that I add one variable into struct A, then set function was working as expected (but final structure was bigger)

*Of course there exists different ways how to deal with this (for example with unions) but I only playing with this and I interested why this is not working.*

Comment: the result you get depends on endianess and your code has multiple undefined behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class `A` the `set` function is really

```
void set(const uint32_t val) {
    (*this).operator=(*reinterpret_cast<const A *>(&val));
}
```

That will invoke the automatically generated `A::operator=` function. But since `A` doesn't have any member variables to be copied, it does nothing.

---

And now that you've done your experiment, please don't do anything like that ever again.

Comment: So, this mean that if struct has no member variables, then it is not a struct? something like namespace only ?

Comment: @vlk Not quite like a namespace, since the member functions are not `static`, and you can not add members to the structure like you can with a namespace. A `struct` is still a `struct` that can (if you don't explicitly prevent it with a deleted constructor or some such) be instantiated as an object.

Comment: @vlk Of course it is a `struct`. As long as you use the keyword `struct`, then it is a `struct` (or in C++ you may call it `class`). The only thing that is exceptional is that trivial methods do nothing. And sometimes an "empty struct" is useful, such as in SFINAE technology.